# Is there a function through which when a and b multiplies the resultant x is same,and x is given by the user

Tags: list, linked-list

For example all combinations when multiplied together results in x=20. 
In first sequence, A = 2, B = 10.
`2 x 10 = 20`

```
5 x 4 = 20 etc
```

The sequences are required must be present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem of number theory and there are several algorithms of varying complexity which can be used to perform an “integer factorisation”. The fastest would be the *[general number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)*. There are several good examples for quadratic sieves that you can compare as well (e.g. [SIMPQS](http://www.friedspace.com/QS/)). If you aren’t considering using it in a productive manner I recommend to look into *Dixon's factorization method*, since it’s a bit more comprehensible.